# catching a cyrillic route in laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-routing

**What im trying to achieve**

I wish to catch (for example) `http://www.my-domain/Цезаря-Цезаря-1` which in my code would translate to `http://www.my-domain/{slug}-{id}` Now the problem is that :

- my regular expression skills are rusty
- things that work on regexr.com do not work in laravel
- I'm  getting 404s for no reason.

**What have I tried**
I am now catching the slug with `{any}` But i'd rather contain it to only `[a-z0-9-]+` <- This works for latin. But I would also like to add Cyrillic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it works without a problem.

For example:

```
Route::get('Б/{x}', function($x) {
    return "Route found. x is $x";
});
```

And when I run url `http://domain/Б/Ж-Зa`, output I get is `Route found. x is Ж-Зa`

**EDIT**

You can use the following rule for that:

```
Route::get('{slug}-{id}', function($slug, $id) {
    return "route found<br />slug is {$slug}<br />id is $id";
})->where('slug', '[^/]*')->where('id', '\d*');
```

or even:

```
Route::get('{slug}-{id}', function($slug, $id) {
    return "route found<br />slug is {$slug}<br />id is $id";
})->where('slug', '.*')->where('id', '\d*');
```

The result in both cases is:

```
route found
slug is Цезаря-Цезаря
id is 1
```

Comment: I need {cyrillic/latin/-}-{integer+}

It fails on the `-` parts of cyrillic.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry Show exactly what doesn't work - your route, your url and what you want to have in your variables